# Cancel update of single field on MS Access 2007 bound form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I may be overthinking this, but I see all sorts of potential problems....

I have a table that I'll call Master. Among other items, it contains a field called Serial. I *thought* this would be a static item--i.e., that it would never change (once initially assigned), for any given row in Master. I now find out that it *can* change, and not only that, I need to store history of those changes.

I can break Serial out into a separate table, where each row will have a MasterId, EffectiveDate and Termination Date (the current Serial for a Master row would be the one (and only one--code-enforced) row with a Null TerminationDate). So far, so good....

Now the problem that I'm asking about: I have a bound form built on a Select from Master that includes Serial.

What I *think* I want to do, to make this changeability transparent to the user, is to short-circuit any changes that are made to the Serial text box, probably in the text box BeforeUpdate event. I'd then use code to Terminate the current row in the Serial table & insert a new row, which becomes current and is displayed in the text box. I would (I think) need to cancel the update in the form's recordset, *without* losing any changes the user has made to other fields....

It's at this point that my brain goes out to lunch, since I'm still much more comfortable with unbound forms & Save buttons. Can I do this, as proposed? What tricks & traps do I need to know about? If need be, I can make the Serial field on the form read-only, and require a pop-up to edit it, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

****EDIT**

Hope this helps:

**Before**

```
table Master
  Id             AutoNumber  PK
  Serial         Text(20)
  --other fields
```

Current frmMaster RecordSource:

```
SELECT Id, Serial, yada, yada FROM Master WHERE blahBlah
```

**After**

```
table Master
  Id             AutoNumber  PK
  --other fields

table Serial
  Id             AutoNumber  PK
  MasterId       Long
  Serial         Text(20)
  EffDt          Date/Time
  TermDt         Date/Time
```

New frmMaster RecordSource:

```
SELECT Master.Id, Serial.Serial, yada, yada 
FROM Master LEFT JOIN Serial ON Master.Id = Serial.MasterId 
WHERE Serial.TermDt is Null AND blahBlah
```

An "edit" on the form should result in:

1. Selected row in Serial gets TermDt filled (Now()). NO CHANGE is to be made to the value of Serial.Serial on this row.
2. A new row in Serial is created, with new Serial, same MasterId and EffDt = Now()
3. New Serial displayed on form, preferably such that it looks to the user as if they'd just edited in place.
4. Any changes made to other fields on the form get saved.

**EDIT, again**

Okay, so HansUp has given an answer that looks like it covers most of what I need. My remaining stumbling block may not even be an issue (though if that's the case, can someone explain why?).

The use case of adding a Master is pretty straightforward, but in the use case of an update that changes the Serial I'm still confused: if `txtSerial` is bound to `Serial.Serial`, and the user changes the contents of `txtSerial`, won't Access attempt to Update the contents of `Serial.Serial` to match? How does Adding a Serial row on change (which looks like it should work a treat), prevent the Update of the existing Serial row?

Comment: This is a tough one to visualize, IMO.  Show us samples with relevant fields from your Master and SerialHistory tables.

Comment: In your example, does the Serial field become part of the Master table AND the Serial table?

Comment: What is EffDt and how do you pronounce it?

Comment: Seems to me Master should have a field, Serial_ID, as a foreign key to Serial.ID.

Comment: EffDt is EffectiveDate--I have a habit of abreviating left over from when I worked with DBAs that _required_ it.

Comment: I s'pose I could have keys going both ways, but Serial _has to_ carry a MasterId so that I'll know which Master a no-longer-current Serial applied to after that SerialId is removed from Master on a change.

Comment: Apparently you intend to use the Serial table's TermDt field to designate which Serial.Serial value is currently "active" for a given Master.ID row.  (if TermDt is Null -> that's the one)  Beyond that use, what is the purpose of the TermDt and EffDt fields?  How will your application use the information those fields contain?  Another way to look at this is how would your application suffer with single Date/Time field (instead of 2) in the Serial table?

Comment: So far this discussion has focused on updates to existing Master rows.  How will you handle INSERTs of new Master rows?  You're storing MasterId in the Serial table.  And that corresponds to Id in the Master table.  But Id is an autonumber, so its value is not known until after the Master row has been INSERTed.  Will you defer creating the Serial row until after the Master INSERT has been completed?

Comment: I foresee having to ask "For this Master, what was its Serial on X past date?" With the two dates in the record, I can build a Where clause with Between. Also "What Serials have been assigned to this Master? When were they active?" And "Is this Serial active, and if so which Master is it?" I _think_ that all those questions will be easier to answer with two dates.

Comment: Yes, I'll have to create a Master record before I can create a Serial record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us sample data for the Serial table.  I'm curious whether it could look like this:

```
Id MasterId Serial  date_added
 1        1 foo      4/21/2011 7:00:00 AM
 2        1 bar      4/21/2011 9:00:00 AM
 3        1 foo      4/21/2011 11:00:00 AM
 4        2 asldkjf  4/4/2011 1:00:00 PM
```

Whenever you need the Serial rows expressed with EffDt and TermDt, you can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    s.Id,
    s.MasterId,
    s.Serial,
    s.date_added AS EffDt,
    (SELECT TOP 1 sub.date_added
    FROM Serial As Sub
    WHERE
        sub.MasterId = s.MasterId
        And sub.date_added > s.date_added
    ORDER BY sub.date_added) AS TermDt
FROM Serial AS s
ORDER BY
    s.MasterId,
    s.date_added;
```

I realize your question is broader.  For now, this piece is one I can wrap my head around.  But does it fit your requirements?

**Update**: I used my version of the Serial table. And I created a Master table with autonumber Id, text Serial, plus 2 other text fields, Other_field1 and Other_field2.  Then created a simple continuous form bound to "SELECT Id, Serial, Other_field1, Other_field2 FROM Master Order By Id;".

Here is the form's code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim varSerialOldvalue As Variant

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    addSerialRow
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSql As String
    If Me.txtSerial.value <> varSerialOldvalue Then
        addSerialRow
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    varSerialOldvalue = Me.txtSerial.OldValue
End Sub

Private Sub addSerialRow()
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    strSql = "INSERT INTO Serial(MasterId, Serial, date_added)" & _
        vbNewLine & "VALUES(" & Me.txtid & ",'" & _
        Replace(Me.txtSerial, "'", "''") & "', #" & _
        Format(Now(), "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") & "#);"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.description _
        & ") in procedure addSerialRow" & vbNewLine & _
        "SQL: " & strSql
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

Is that a useful starting point for what you want to accomplish?

**Update2**: You said *txtSerial is bound to Serial.Serial*; but my approach binds txtSerial directly to a Serial field in the Master table ... which is what I thought you originally proposed.  What is wrong with that approach now?

Comment: This does show me how to use only one date. It doesn't answer my main question--I'll have to give some more thought to another Edit to see if I can make that clearer.

Comment: Reading this again, it does do _most_ of what I need. See my most recent Edit for the one thing I'm still stuck on....

Comment: Good.  Wasn't sure about Nulls for Serial; figured you could sort that out if needed.  What is the one sticking point now?  I read your edit from yesterday, but I'm not seeing what you want me to see I guess.

Comment: The Edit I was talking about wasn't there until just now, as I wrote the comment first. I s'pose I should know enough to create the "object" (Edit) before I reference it....

Comment: Aha!  Yeah, I refreshed the page to check for a more recent update, but must have pulled the trigger too fast.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't as clear as I could have been.... Before/After in my first Edit are permanent strucural changes that I'm proposing to make, and in the After version of the table structure `Master.Serial` no longer exists. I s'pose I could leave it, but it would be a denormalization, which I tend to resist. Though this might be thorny enough problem--as I'm approaching it at present, at least--to justify doing so.

Comment: The more I think about it, though, the more I come to this as well. I'll leave `Master.Serial` in place and add the table `Serial` as `SerialHistory` instead. The current `Serial` (value) will always be right there in `Master`, and `SerialHistory` will only need to be read for *history* questions. Accepting Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do not see why you want to prevent the change to the text box? If I am reading this correct, what you are saying is if the text box changes, then you need to save the previous current data and record before changes?

If above is the case, then simply in the after update event of the serial text box, run an append query that takes the current record from the table and copies (appends it somewhere else).

While you have a bound form, the changes to controls on the form are NOT YET committed to the actual underlying table. If your code or a process or a some append query or VBA code looks at or makes a copy of that row from the table, all of the old values will still be intact.

So a bound form does not mean each change in a text box is written to the table, but in fact the whole record is ONLY written to the table when the record is saved, and that is why the forms before update event has a cancel that can prevent the record write from occurring until your rules etc are met.

So you just need one or two lines in the serial box after update event (that event does not fire unless changes are made to the text box) to copy the current record from the table which will have all of the old values, including the old serial number.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying--but if I do, I don't think it will work the way I want it to. See Edit.

Comment: Hmmm... More I think about it, maybe I *could* insert a (copied) Serial row & update the TermDt of *that* row, then just let the save go forward, then update the EffDt of the changed Serial row.... But that seems complicated & error prone. Maybe.

Comment: It was not clear that you simply want an audit. In the forms serial text box before update event you can use the textbox.old value, and set a form level variable and you thus have new and old value.

AT this point in time, the user will may want to hit undo and not save the whole record. You thus should not updating that serial (audit) table.

If record to be saved, then forms after update if old serial <> current then then simple write out a new record with the new value + date + time etc. If not a new serial value, you still able to update the existing serial row time/date update values.

Answer (score 0):

If Master doesn't change too often and isn't too large, then when saving, append the entire Master record with a whoChanged record added and a timefield.  Then when you want to see changes in Serial, just do a GroupBy on Serial and you can see the times and who changed it.

This is overkill for one field, but in general provides a good way of recording changes.